# DataTables plugin doesn't like nice combined with Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-4

So, I am making a website for a school projects, which needs to include a sortable user system.

When I was making it, I thought it would be nice to use the datatables plugin to make this process a lot easier. But when I used it combined with Bootstrap 4, my table doesn't stretch out and I feel like the bootstrap CSS doesn't really work combined with it.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make these 4 work together to make it look nicer?

This is how ugly the site looks now:

[image]

My HTML / PHP of the tab:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row" id="content">

     <!-- Bovenste text van de site -->
     <div class="col-12">
         <p class="text-center" id="introtext">Hier ziet u een overzicht van alle contactpersonen.</p>
     </div>

     <table id="sortableTable" class="table table-hover">
         <thead>
         <tr>
             <td>Voornaam</td>
             <td>Achternaam</td>
             <td>Email</td>
             <td>Telefoonnummer</td>
             <td>Gebruikersnaam</td>
             <td>Type account</td>
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr>
             <?php

             foreach ($row = mysqli_fetch_row(displayUsers("localhost", "root", "", "adresboek")) as $value
             {
                 echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
             }

             ?>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
     </table>
 </div> </div>
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific what you mean with "to make it look nicer"?

Comment: Make it use predefined classes that bootstrap uses and make it stretch to the full width of the container. Like in this https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

I just cant figure out how to make it work together.

Comment: Include all of the relevent code.

Comment: Nevermind. I just made it work, only the button looks really weird when being hovered on... https://gyazo.com/8fe154098b92e2892dd2dc222038f58f

anyone has an idea how to make this look better without adding tons of CSS??

Comment: Here is the answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51442227/9750031

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the provided link https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 . it seems that you forget to include Datatables Bootstrap 4 JS/CSS files:
JS:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js
```

CSS:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css
```

Make sure that the above custom JS/CSS Datatables Bootstrap 4 are included in your page.